# Чекбокс "запомнить меня" в форме входа на сайт

Tags: php, сессия

Вот прислали мне тестовое задание, а там нужно сделать форму, чтобы был пункт "запомнить меня". Я это сделаю,если пойму зачем он нужен. Когда при входе на сайт создается сессионная переменная ($_SESSION['user'] например), то, насколько я понимаю, после закрытия окна браузера она никуда и не девается. Я могу выйти и снова благополучно войти на сайт уже без формы входа. Зачем тогда "запомнить меня"? Подскажите, если я чего-то не догоняю.
Я пишу так:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
  // форма для входа
  $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
 } else {
  // основной контент
 }
```

Это работает без "запомнить меня". Так же тоже все работает?

Comment: это опция для куки, чтобы не удалять ее после перезапуска браузера.

Comment: обновил вопрос. Не пойму - "запомнить меня" делает то же самое?

Comment: отсутствие "запомнить меня" традиционно указывает серверной программе сделать куку временной. что тут не понятно.

Comment: Теперь все понятно. "запомнить меня" делает expires максимально долгим. Интересно, по умолчанию какое время жизни куки?

Comment: >по умолчанию какое время жизни куки?

до закрытия браузера.

Comment: @klopp, ничего подобного. Только что закрыл браузер, открыл - все ок. Я существую! Поэтому и вопрос задаю -  в чем тогда дело?

Comment: Понятия не имею. Я ж не вижу ваших кук. Посмотрите у себя в браузере подробную информацию - какая именно кука, на какой срок. Включите режим отладки и ловите их установку, etc. 
А как кука ведёт себя по умолчанию написано в RFC, и спорить с этим бессмысленно.

Comment: Моих кук и не надо видеть - они все по умолчанию ведут себя стандартно. Код:

echo isset($_SESSION['user'])? echo $_SESSION['user']: "";
$_SESSION['user'] = 'Root';

Этот код после первого запуска всегда будет выдавать root.Открыл я браузер, закрыл - все равно root. Вопрос был в том, когда эта сессия самоуничтожится.

Comment: процесс уничтожения файлов сессий в php слегка запутан, он зависит от переменных php.ini session.gc_probability , session.gc_divisor и session.gc_maxlifetime . а вот токен авторизации хранится в куке и управляется браузером.

Comment: >Моих кук и не надо видеть

Странно слышать это от человека, называющего себя разработчиком :) Чудес не бывает, кука без expires живёт только до закрытия браузера, так и только так. Если кажется, что это не так, значит, либо где-то expires выставляется, либо задействованы какие-то ещё куки. И выяснить это можно только одним способом: посмотреть на куки глазами.